# Second level menu is not opening only in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having an issue with the second level menu only in Safari. Top level and submenu work fine on mouse hover on chrome, firefox etc but when opened in Safari, only first menu is opening on hover. I have already tried other solutions available here and on other forums but it's still same.

```css
.nav {
    margin: 2% 10% 0 35%;
    /*margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 10%;*/
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav-container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-container a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-pos {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-pos-sp {
    /*padding-left: 30px;*/
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 1%;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-nav-menu a {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 12px;
    border-bottom: thin solid #fff;
    background-color: #343434;
}

/* child menu dropdown */
.navbar-nav-child {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.navbar-nav-menu-item-101a:hover .navbar-nav-child {
        margin-left: 200px !important;
        display: block !important;
}

.navbar-nav-menu-child-text a {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px 0px 15px 12px;
        border-bottom: thin solid #fff;
        background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.services:hover .navbar-nav-menu {
        display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/all.css.cf.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-pos nav-pos-sp services">
            <a href="#0" target="_blank">First Menu <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
            <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-menu navbar-nav-services">
                <ul>
                    <li class="navbar-nav-menu-item-101a"><a href="#0">Second Level Menu <span class="fa fa-angle-right"
                                                                                                                                                          style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"></span></a>
                        <div class="navbar-nav-child navbar-nav-menu-child-text">

                            <a href="#0" target="_blank">1</a>
                            <a href="#0" target="_blank">2</a>
                            <a href="#0" target="_blank">3</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have included the HTML and CSS code for the menu. I have also checked it on chrome using windows OS, and it works but the only issue is with safari browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions I have that may help.

Firstly, I would not recommend using `position: fixed;` to position your submenus because `fixed` is a position relative to the browser window.  You likely want the submenus to be positioned according to the parent, not the window.

Secondly, you have `overflow: hidden;` on `.navbar-nav`, which means anything that falls outside the borders of it should be invisible - which would include your submenus.

Here is a JSFiddle with a working example of your snippet with my suggestions, tested and working in Safari:

```css
.nav {
  margin: 2% 10% 0 35%;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav-container a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-pos {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-pos-sp {}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 1%;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  color: #C7C7C7;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav-menu a {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 12px;
  border-bottom: thin solid #fff;
  background-color: #343434;
}

/* child menu dropdown */

.navbar-nav-child {
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  color: #C7C7C7;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav-menu-item-101a:hover .navbar-nav-child {
  display: block !important;
}

.navbar-nav-menu-child-text a {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 12px;
  border-bottom: thin solid #fff;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.services:hover .navbar-nav-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/all.css.cf.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-pos nav-pos-sp services">
          <a href="#0" target="_blank">First Menu <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
          <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-menu navbar-nav-services">
            <ul>
              <li class="navbar-nav-menu-item-101a"><a href="#0">Second Level Menu <span class="fa fa-angle-right"
                                                                                                                                                          style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;"></span></a>
                <div class="navbar-nav-child navbar-nav-menu-child-text">

                  <a href="#0" target="_blank">1</a>
                  <a href="#0" target="_blank">2</a>
                  <a href="#0" target="_blank">3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m59vk802/4/

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but its still the same on safari but then when I change the position of `navbar-nav` to a relative from fixed, then on chrome when submenu becomes visible the other menu from the first menu alter their position. I tried to make these changes on jsfiddle and it works, but again when made these changes on webstorm and opened the file on safari, it remains same.

Comment: @Nix Did you check-in and make sure the old code wasn't cached and that the changes loaded? Do you have a live url that we can see?